# how to boolean multiple objects at the same time

Tags: mesh, modifiers, add-on, shortcut

i wanted to make a character made completely out of cabels, so i used cylinders in the position that i wanted because bezier circles were not working the way i wanted them too, however after finishing the head, i wanted to add eyes and a mouth, so i used a template i made to see if i can but it inside, click boolean and it would cut out the eye holes, but its not working, am i doing something incorrect, if anyone has any answers or solutions for a different way that would be great
[image]

i want the end result to be similar to this sculpt i made, with the holes going through the mesh if you get what i mean [image]

Comment: pls provide blend file ...or just search here for boolean modifier. There were lots of questions about it

Comment: alright, how should i send the file

Comment: open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/b/XJbSVzY6

Comment: It's better to use textures in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this settings:

[image]

1. i changed from collection to object
2. i choosed toppart as object
3. i applied scale + rotation

Then select your "toppart" object and hide it.

I hope this is what you wanted to make.

here is the blend file:

[image]

[image]

Comment: you mean the ends of each pipe?

Comment: i updated my answer.

Comment: i have updated my question if it helps understand in anyway :)

Comment: if my answer helped you, pls click on the checkmark left of my answer. if it doesn't, please tell me what's not working?

Comment: i have tried what you said however nothing is changing except the eye template warping in the center

Comment: i uploaded the blend file so hopefully you now "see" the difference i made

Comment: oh thats strange how that works

Comment: thank you it does work

Comment: glad i could help